# Comparing system time to field value using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need some assistance with writting a VB function to compare the system time with my column 1 datetime variables, and return a different color background. Here is the condition...

- if scheduledTime is 0-15mins late, then background row color red
- if scheduledTime is 15mins-30mins late, then background row color yellow
- if scheduledTime is 30mins-2hours late, then background row color green

---

Row Rendered event:

```
 Row_Rendered();

 DateTime systemTime = DateTime.Now();
 DateTime fieldTime = SCHD_DTM.CurrentValue;
 DateTime result As Integer = DateTime.Compare(fieldTime,systemTime).TotalMinutes

 if result <= 0.25 Then 
     RowATTrs("style") = "background-color:Red";

 else if result > 0.25 & result <- 0.5 Then 
     RowATTrs("style") = "background-color:Yellow";

 else if result > 0.5 & result <= 2 Then
     RowATTrs("style") = "background-color:Green";

 End If
```

This is what I had and Im getting no response...

Comment: It might be just me but it looks like you're doing the settings after the rows have been rendered (this also sends the data to the client).

Comment: You are mixing C# and VB ;)

Comment: The line DateTime result As Integer = DateTime.Compare(fieldTime,systemTime).TotalMinutes makes no sense. DateTime.Compare returns an integer and TotalMinutes is a member of TimeSpan class, which would be returned if you do a DateTime.Subtract (which isn't what the code does...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Im getting no response" is not a good description of an error or undesired behaviour. However, you are mixing C# and VB.NET in your code. Of course that won't compile.

But this should:

```
Dim systemTime As date = Date.Now
Dim fieldTime As Date = SCHD_DTM.CurrentValue
Dim result As Double= (fieldTime - systemTime).TotalMinutes

If result <= 0.25 Then
    RowATTrs("style") = "background-color:Red"
ElseIf result > 0.25 & result < -0.5 Then
    RowATTrs("style") = "background-color:Yellow"
ElseIf result > 0.5 & result <= 2 Then
    RowATTrs("style") = "background-color:Green"
End If
```

However, not sure if `fieldTime` is  supposed to be lower  than `Date.Now`. Then swap the variables in `(fieldTime - systemTime)`.

Comment: Thanks, your right I was mixing the two languages lol. Im very new to this and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datediff function to find out what you want,

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, systemTime, fieldTime)
```

will return a long telling you the number of minutes between the two datetimes.